# How can i render another file in react native without onPress event

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For example:-

```
const [showWebView,setShowWebView] = useState(true);
{
showWebView ? (
// code within if condition
):

(
// code within else condition
)
```

**I want to render my file within else condition. How can i render my file without onPress event**

**I am new in react native.
Thanks in advance for the help**

Answer (score 0):

**Well i have found ans to this question**
For this we have to use **useNavigation** hook(dont forget to install it.)

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
const {navigate} = useNavigation()


const [showWebView,setShowWebView] = useState(true);
{
showWebView ? (
// code within if condition
):

(
  navigate("Entries")
)
```